# solve a system of k equations with 3 unknowns and l constraints

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, constraints

It has been a while since school, and I need help solving the following system which then I'll have to implement to auto-find the unknown coefficients.

Find $x_i$, $y_i$ and $z_i$ such that:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{1} y_{1} z_{1} m_{1} = M_{1} = T n_{1}\\
x_{2} y_{2} z_{2} m_{2} = M_{2} = T n_{2}\\
\cdots \\
x_{9} y_{9} z_{9} m_{9} = M_{9} = T n_{9}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Given that:

- $T$, $m_{i}$ and $n_{i}$ are known constants
- $T,\, x_{i},\, m_{i},\, M_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$
- $\sum_{i} n_{i} = 1$ with 0 < $n_{i}$ < 1
- $\sum_{i} M_{i} = \sum_{i} T n_{i} = T$
- $x_{i}\in [1,+\infty [$ must be as small as possible
- $y_{i}\in \{4,5,6\}$
- $z_{i}\in \{1,4,30\}$

All advices are welcome, or at least point me to the right direction. :-)

Comment: Constants $T,m_i,n_i$ cannot be arbitrary since $1\le x_i=\frac{Tn_i}{y_iz_im_i}$ implies $y_iz_i\le\frac{Tn_i}{m_i}$ and $y_iz_i$ have nine fixed    possibilities.

Comment: These constants change regularly, hence the need of re-calculating the unknown variables everytime

Comment: Your formulation doesn't make sense: bullets 3 and 4 contradict each other because, if $\sum n_i = 1$ and $M_i = T n_i$ (as stated in the system of equations), then $\sum M_i = \sum T n_i = T \sum n_i = T$, so not only is $\sum M_i$ *"as close as possible to $T$"*, but it is in fact exactly $T$.

Comment: @AlexM. so far these coef. are being found manually, so we do accept some margin between that sum & T, hence the wrong formulation. Fixed :-)

Comment: Your problem looks like minimizing/maximizing the weights of parallelepipedic boxes in order to fill in the best way a certain volume, with additional constraints.

Comment: I still have difficulty understanding the question. Could you give an example showing what objects are know, and what objcs have to be found? Also, "a small as possible" can mean more than one thing. Is there a function of the x_i used to measured their smallness? I mean is x_1=1, x_2=3 better than x_1=2 and x_2 =2?

Answer (score 2):

$x_{k} y_{k} z_{k} m_{k} = M_{k} = T n_{k}$

Set all unknowns on the left:

$x_{k} y_{k} z_{k}  = \frac{M_{k}}{m_{k}} = \frac{T n_{k}}{m_{k}}$

You want to minimize $x_k$.

There are only $9$ unique combinations of $y_k z_k = [4,5,6,16,20,24,120,150,180]$

Modulo  $\frac{M_{k}}{m_{k}}$ by the largest to smallest $y_k z_k$ until you get an integer :

i.e. $\frac{M_{k}}{m_{k}} \equiv 0$ (mod $y_k z_k$)

Then  $x_k = \frac{M_{k}}{m_{k} y_k z_k}$ is the smallest $x_k$.

$y_k$ and  $z_k$ are uniquely determined by the largest $y_k z_k$ divisor above.

Comment: $n_i$ are absolutely not null, actually they are positive numbers. I should've mentionned that. I just gave this a fast look and will get back to it tomorrow. Feel free to edit/ask questions till then if needed

Comment: @Enissay : are the $n_i$ integers or reals?

Comment: @Enissay : Everything on the left of $x_{k} y_{k} z_{k} m_{k} = T n_{k}$ is an integer so $T n_{k}$ will be an integer and both $T$ and $n_k$ are known so the method still works.

Comment: @Enissay : my edit was wrong so I removed it.

Comment: Actually they are real numbers 0 < $n_{i}$ < 1

Comment: Well, I gave it a try yesterday, and it looks like the $\frac{M_{k}}{m_{k}}$ is a decimal, meaning that Modulus is never null, and thus an integer $x_i$ cannot be found this way. I tried to make sense of it like taking the closer integer, but I'm not done yet as it was late and my brain started boiling with all the numbers/decimals... I'll try again this week-end. Maybe you can give me some ideas before then :P

Comment: If  $\frac{M_{k}}{m_{k}}$ is a decimal then $x_{k} y_{k} z_{k} $ cannot be an integer. It must be an integer if its a product of three integers. If you can add an example I'll look at it. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of adding one. Will do this evening when back home (or maybe before if I've time). Cheers